# lower bound of expectation of stochastic differential equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm looking for a lower bound on the expected value of a smooth, non-negative, increasing function $\mathbb{E}f(X_t)$, $f(0)=0$ of the solution to a stochastic differential equation $X_t = x + \int_0^t b(X_s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s) dw_s$  ($x>0$).

I'm aware of many *upper* bounds based on linear growth and Lipschitz constants, e.g., $\mathbb{E}|X_t|^p \le Ce^{\alpha t}$ or $\mathbb{E}|X_t-X_s|^p \le Cg(|t-s|)$, etc.

For a lower bound I've played around with the second moment method, the reverse Markov inequality (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83762/reverse-markov-inequality-for-non-negative-unbounded-random-variables)), and flipped through Oksendal, K&S, R&Y, and Mao, but I'm stumped. From Markov's inequality and a Girsanov argument I can show that for any $t>0$, $\mathbb{E}f(X_t) \ge P[f(X_t)>1]>0$. However, I'm not aware of any results based on linear growth or Lipschitz constants in a similar manner to the results mentioned above, something like, say, $\mathbb{E}|X_t|^p \ge Cg(t)$ for some decreasing function $g(t)$. Is anyone aware of a result like this?

Comment: So do you mean, that $f$ is smooth, non-negative and increasing, or $\Bbb Ef(X_t)$ is?

Comment: $f$ is, but since one could just make assumptions on $f$ (like $f(x)\ge|x|^p$) I'm more interested in $\mathbb{E}|X_t|^p \ge $ [something]

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: all the non-decreasing functions you mention, like $|x|^p$, also happen to be convex. If you can bound the drift term below, say by $b(x)\geq \beta$, then you can use Jensen's inequality:
$$ \mathbb{E}f(X_t) \geq f(\mathbb{E}X_t) \geq f(x + \beta t), $$
because $\mathbb{E}X_t \geq x+\beta t$.